# Gradle how to modify file path before adding to war?

Tags: gradle, war, filepath

Gradle war plugin:

How to modify path name before adding to war?

```
war {
    from ("../common/conf") {
        include 'foo.xml'
        include 'bar.xml'

        eachFile {details ->
            details.path = 'META-INF/' + details.path
        }
        into 'WEB-INF/classes'
    }
}
```

It should be

```
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/foo.xml
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/bar.xml
```

but it is:

```
META-INF/WEB-INF/classes/foo.xml
META-INF/WEB-INF/classes/bar.xml
```

How to execute `eachFile` before `into`?

Comment: And why not `into 'WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/'`?

Comment: this is just a simple example. it can be more complex like pattern replacement.

Comment: well, then do the replacement like `details.path = details.path.replaceFirst(/^WEB-INF\/classes/, 'WEB-INF/classes/META-INF')`?

Comment: In the specific case you mention, you could also use a subspec like this: `into('WEB-INF/classes') { from("../common/conf") { include 'foo.xml'; include 'bar.xml'; into 'META-INF' } }`

Comment: Thanks. It is quite flexible. But it would be nice if gradle honors the order of methods inside a closure.

Comment: It *does* honor the order of methods. The point is, that you only do configuration. You give the `eachFile` method a `Closure` that will be evaluated when its time and you give the `into` method a `String` that is used when its time. This has nothing to do with the execution, that happens at a later stage. And at execution, the `eachFile` closure is invoked with the final path of the file.